# Count intersections Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a (:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Channel) schama.
I would like to count all possible channel intersections.
For finding all channel combinations I used `apoc.coll.combination`.
After searching a bit found this [Filter to the nodes in common by the count of input nodes in the match](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/#_filter_to_the_nodes_in_common_by_the_count_of_input_nodes_in_the_match) tried to apply same idea, the follow it the cypher I got into.

```
match (c:Channel)
with collect(c) as channels
with apoc.coll.combinations(channels, 1, size(channels)) as combinations
unwind combinations as combination
match (u:User)-->(c:Channel) where c in combination
with *, count(DISTINCT c) as ccount, size(combinations) as csize
where ccount = csize
return c.name, count(distinct u)
```

Just for testing I changed combinations calls to min and max 2. But got an empty set as result. Am I missing something? What is the easiest way to count users that follows a list of channels?

Is Neo4J the right tool for this job?

Comment: Are you sure `csize` should be `size(combinations)`? If possible can you provide some sample data, with the expected output?

Comment: Thank you very much @CharchitKapoor for taking your time. Yeah, this `csize = ccount` is not clear to me. I made this copying the link example posted in question where it says it's the most efficient way to find an intersection. In this link I've uploaded the neo4j data folder. https://0x0.st/oW_3.zst

Comment: I got the data, can you please elaborate what results do you expect from the query?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor something like `["historia_public", "some_other_channel"] | 2200` the count for those should not be bigget than biggest nor smaller than smallest channel. Just counting users that have relations for both "historia_public" and "some_other_channel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
match (u:User)-[:SUBSCRIBE]->(c:Channel) WITH u, collect(id(c)) AS userChannels, collect(c.name) AS channelNames
match (c:Channel)
with u, userChannels, channelNames, collect(id(c)) as channels
with apoc.coll.combinations(channels, 1, size(channels)) as combinations, u, userChannels, channelNames
unwind combinations as combination
WITH u, userChannels, channelNames, combination WHERE size(combination) = size(userChannels) AND ALL(x IN userChannels WHERE x IN combination)
RETURN channelNames, count(u) AS usersCount
```

In this query, we collect the channel ids and names in two lists for each user.
Then, we calculate all the channels nodes combinations. And at the end after unwinding the combinations, we check if the size of the `combination` list and `userChannels` list is the same, if it's we compare the contents. Finally, for each combination, we return the user count.

To answer if neo4j is the right tool for the job, it can be provided that the dataset is bounded in some sense. The current query is basically going over each node and relation present in the database, and also with time, the combinations will also increase, so the scaling might become a problem.

Try this query, this will give the expected counts:

```
match (c:Channel)
with collect(c.name) as channels
with apoc.coll.combinations(channels, 1, size(channels)) as combinations
match (u:User)-[:SUBSCRIBE]->(c:Channel)
with u, collect(c.name) AS userChannels, combinations
UNWIND combinations AS combination
WITH combination, u WHERE size(combination) <= size(userChannels) and apoc.coll.containsAll(userChannels, combination)
return combination, count(distinct u)
```

Comment: Hi there, values didn't matched. For example, the set "Historia Publica" that is the biggest one should be about 44k. But in this result it returns about 23k

Comment: Added a new query